# The first row of data in an SSRS report overlaps the other data when viewed in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, row, overlap, ssrs-tablix

I am working on a VB.NET application that has an integrated report viewer to view SSRS reports.  Most of the reports can be viewed just fine.  However, there are three specific SSRS reports that are giving me problems.

Specifically, these reports all have scrolling headers, so that they are always visible as I scroll up and down on the report.  They work exactly how I want them to work when I view them in a web browser.  However, when I view these three reports in the VB.NET application I am working on, the first row of data directly underneath the header scrolls right along with the header, overlapping the data that I would like to see.  Strangely, this is only a problem on the first page of the report, and none of the subsequent pages have this problem.

Nothing that I have done in ReportBuilder has solved this problem.  Here are the properties for the Static row group underneath the header row:

```
FixedData = False
HideIfNoRows = False
KeepTogether = False
KeepWithGroup = None
RepeatOnNewPage = False
```

Here are the properties for the Static row group representing the Header row:

```
FixedData = True
HideIfNoRows = False
KeepTogether = False
KeepWithGroup = After
RepeatOnNewPage = True
```

Any assistance anyone can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to give a little space between your header and your first row?

Comment: Do you mean a blank row between the header and the first row of data?  That would solve my problem, I know because I've tried that.  However, that's not what my employer is looking for.

Comment: Yah. Its my alternative way. I'm also looking forward to your question for a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If changing the properties for the Static row group representing the Header row and the Static row group underneath the header row doesn't work, try making the columns of your header wider, or the header row itself taller.  When there is too little space between the header row and the row underneath the header row, that can cause the data beneath the header row to overlap the data you are trying to view when the header stays visible as you scroll up and down the page.  This is more likely to be a problem if the text on any of your header columns gets pushed to two lines.